# How to place a view between two other views in a veritcal arrangement in CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a layout file in which I'm using a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` together with a `RecyclerView` and works fine. Now I'm trying to place a `ConstraintLayout` between my `AppBarLayout` and the `RecylerView`. This is what I have tried so far:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="272dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <!--Some views-->
            </RelativeLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!--Some views-->
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/beers_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The problem is, that it remains at the bottom of the activity even if I have places it between `AppBarLayout` and the `RecylerView`. Can anyone please help me place the `ConstraintLayout` view between them? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try put your `RecyclerView` into `ConstraintLayout`?

Below `CollapsingToolbarLayout`:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <!--Your views here with constraints-->

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="your last view"
                 />
    </ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me try this.

Comment: It really worked. That NestedScrollView did the trick ;) Thanks